# Count number of unique values in a column, only add if value in other column is greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider this table:

[image]

I wish to count the number of unique ITEM occurances, but only add if Quantity of the item is greater than 0.

So in this case, the formula should return B, C and D = 3

In another example, the quantity of B was changed, but the result should still be 3, as I wish to sum only unique values from column "Item".

[image]

I am trying to fiddle with this formula, but couldn't figure how to add the "Quantity>0" condition:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A7<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A7;A1:A7&""))
```

This returns the number of unique values without considering quantity.

Is my goal even possible without VBA?

**NOTE:**
Table has blank and text values in some Quantity cells. These lines should be ignored by formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work, even with text or blanks in the Quantity column

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(Quantity)*(Quantity>0),MATCH(Item,Item,0)),ROW(Item)-MIN(ROW(Item))+1),1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(Quantity),Quantity,0)>0,Item,""))>0,MATCH(Item,Item,0)),
IF(LEN(IF(IF(ISNUMBER(Quantity),Quantity,0)>0,Item,""))>0,MATCH(Item,Item,0),""))>0,1))
```

This is an **array** formula so should be confirmed by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Should handle blanks and text in column B.